# Pray they can hold it in for two hours?

Tags: lateral-thinking, real

I use to to help with the nursery at a very small church.  The Nursery was downstairs next to the the two small restrooms for males/females.  Whenever I had to go out to a restroom to get towels or water for the nursery I would often find a small line of individuals waiting to use the restrooms.

Recognizing this as a problem I spoke to our pastor and mentioned a simple change.  Once implemented the length of the lines I would see started to decrease until there was usually not a line left.

What simple change allowed us to decrease the wait for these individuals?

Comment: You asked [the same puzzle](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/2761/30633) some 3 years ago, and it was eventually closed for being too broad  (and, frankly, for not sounding like a *puzzle* either).  The same reasoning applies today. Closing; if you can address these issues, feel free to edit and ask for it to be reopened.

Answer (score 1):

I think the simplest solution would be:

> to change the restrooms from single-gender to unisex (any gender may use either room).

I'm basing this in part on the fact that

> there was one one small line, likely of females. If males and females were waiting, they likely would have formed two separate lines.

So

> multiple women no longer need to wait for a single restroom, as two women can now use restrooms simultaneously.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you

> opened the windowed door separating the church side from the nursery side, so the people lined up on the church side could use the toilet on the nursery side?